# How do I check to see if an absolute path column matches a glob syntax path column in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, scala, pyspark, glob, databricks-sql

I have a dataset that has a glob syntax column (InstallPathRawString) and I need to check to see if this matches the path column (AppPath).

I've seen some posts about os.path.samefile, but can't figure out how to create a udf to check to see if both columns match.

I need my solution to work in databricks, so Pyspark, scala and databricks sql solutions are what I need.

Sample dataset:

| AppPath | AppName | InstallPathRawString | IsMatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9012\Discord.exe | DISCORD.EXE | "?:*\DISCORD\APP*\DISCORD.EXE" | false |
| C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe | CHROME.EXE | "?:*\CHROM*\APPLICATION\CHROME.EXE" | false |

Comment: Please add your expected output.